# Incorrect value print out MySQL+PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that when I want to print out a column with mysqli_fetch_assoc in PHP, I have to use the same column name, but the tables are different, and it's printing out a wrong tables column.

lekerdezesek2.php

```
$lekerdezes2 = lekerdezes2_leker();

while( $egySor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lekerdezes2) ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["nev"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["szoveg"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["elerheto_maxpontszam"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["szoveg"] .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

mysqli_free_result($lekerdezes2);
```

db_functions.php

```
function lekerdezes2_leker() {
if ( !($conn = moodle_csatlakozas()) ) { 
    return false;
}

$result = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT teszt.nev, kerdesek.szoveg, kerdesek.elerheto_maxpontszam, valaszok.szoveg FROM teszt,kerdesek,valaszok WHERE teszt.ID=kerdesek.tesztID AND kerdesek.ID=valaszok.kerdesekID AND valaszok.helyes=1");

mysqli_close($conn);
return $result;
}
```

The final result is the "valaszok.szoveg" value is the same as "kerdesek.szoveg" after print, but it should not.

Final result looks like this:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqeSh.png)

But it's need be to looks like this:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjPOc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the column name `szoveg` is ambiguous.

You can add an alias name to the column in the select clause and use it.

**Syntax**

```
SELECT 
 [column_1 | expression] AS descriptive_name
FROM table_name;
```

**Example**

```
SELECT 
 kerdesek.szoveg AS kerdesek_szoveg
FROM kerdesek;
```

**Modified Query**

```
SELECT 
    teszt.nev,
    kerdesek.szoveg AS kerdesek_szoveg,
    kerdesek.elerheto_maxpontszam,
    valaszok.szoveg 
FROM
    teszt,
    kerdesek,
    valaszok
WHERE
    teszt.ID = kerdesek.tesztID 
    AND kerdesek.ID = valaszok.kerdesekID
    AND valaszok.helyes = 1
```

**Modified Code**

**lekerdezesek2.php**

```
$lekerdezes2 = lekerdezes2_leker();

while( $egySor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lekerdezes2) ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["nev"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["kerdesek_szoveg"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["elerheto_maxpontszam"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $egySor["szoveg"] .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

mysqli_free_result($lekerdezes2);
```

**db_functions.php**

```
function lekerdezes2_leker() {
    if ( !($conn = moodle_csatlakozas()) ) { 
        return false;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT teszt.nev, kerdesek.szoveg AS kerdesek_szoveg, kerdesek.elerheto_maxpontszam, valaszok.szoveg FROM teszt,kerdesek,valaszok WHERE teszt.ID=kerdesek.tesztID AND kerdesek.ID=valaszok.kerdesekID AND valaszok.helyes=1");

    mysqli_close($conn);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: you are awesome! :D